# Desktop.getDesktop.open() in Java fails

Tags: java, javafx

I have this piece of code:

```
public void openSelectedFiles(MouseEvent mouseEvent){
    ListView<String> listView = (ListView<String>) ((Node) mouseEvent.getSource())
        .getScene().lookup("#listOfReferenceFiles");

    String selectedFileString =  listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(Desktop.isDesktopSupported());
    File fileToOpen = new File(selectedFileString);
    System.out.println(fileToOpen.exists());

    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(fileToOpen);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using Java 8, and it seems to be working, until this line:

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(fileToOpen);`

It does not throw an exception, it just freezes my application. Is this a bug?

Comment: the file `fileToOpen` exists?

Comment: I am tempted to answer yes if  System.out.println(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) prints true.

Comment: Yes they print true, and the files exists/

Comment: What platform (Operating system and JRE version) are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

You must check first if desktop is allowed and if file exists to avoid this kind of problems:

```
//first check if Desktop is supported by Platform or not
if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
    System.out.println("Desktop is not supported");
    return;
}

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

// after check if file exists and open it
if(file.exists()) desktop.open(file);
```

Comment: Tried it. Copied exactly the same code. nothing. I get the same